# Simple development of simple curve on a cone

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

Let $\Lambda$ be a cone with apex $a$ and apex angle $\alpha$.  Draw a simple (non-self-intersecting)
curve $C=(x,y)$ on $\Lambda$, and then develop it to a curve
$\overline{C}$ on a plane by rolling $\Lambda$ on that plane,
starting at $x$ and ending at $y$.
I am interested in the conditions under which $C$ develops to a simple curve $\overline{C}$ in the plane. If $C$ is composed of geodesic segments, then $\overline{C}$ is a drawing in the plane
of segments of the same lengths, and meeting at the same angles, as they do on $\Lambda$.
Intuitively, if $C$ crosses each
ray from $a$ on $\Lambda$ at most once, and
if $C$ is drawn with wet ink, $\overline{C}$ is the drawing that results by rolling
$\Lambda$ on the plane, transferring the ink from $x$ to $y$ along $C$.

I know various conditions on $C$ that ensure that $\overline{C}$ is simple, e.g., if $C$ is a convex curve on $\Lambda$, having $\le \pi$ to one side at every point.  One can impose various conditions
on $C$, e.g., that $C$ be closed and encircle the apex $a$.
But perhaps the simplest version is when $C$ is a simple, open curve, in which case the development
from $x$ to $y$ is determined up to rigid motions.

Here is an example that shows that not all curves $C$ on a cone develop without intersection.
Here $\alpha=\frac{3}{4}\pi$, and the cone is shown cut opened by two different generators
in (a) and (b) below.  The development $\overline{C}$ is shown in (c).

 [image: Cone curve development]

<sub>(This figure is adapted from one in the paper,
"Conical Existence of Closed Curves on Convex Polyhedra," [arXiv:1102.0823](http://arxiv.org/abs/1102.0823).)</sub>

I suspect the analogous problem on a sphere is difficult, but I am hoping that on a cone
it is much simpler.  I would appreciate any even tangential references or ideas.  Thanks!

Comment: @Joseph: Could you explain what exactly do you mean by "develop"? 
My definition would be: Lift $C$ to a curve $\tilde{C}$ in the universal cover $U$ of $\Lambda \setminus \{v\}$. Then $U$ is a flat surface, so it has a developing map $dev: U\to R^2$. Now, take $\bar{C}=dev(\tilde{C})$. Is it what you mean? 

Comment: @Misha: I tried to clarify in the case when $C$ is piecewise geodesic. I *think* this is the same as your definition...

Comment: @Joseph: Two definitions are the same for curves that avoid the apex  $a$. One can also rephrase the definition as follows (for general piecewise-smooth simple curves which are disjoint from the apex): Take a small open neighborhood $N$ of $C$. Then $N$ is simply-connected and has flat Riemannian metric. Thus, there exists a (unique up to postcomposition with isometries of $R^2$) locally-isometric map $f: N\to R^2$. The image $f(C)$ is the *development* of $C$. 